# Reading data file into python in then counting occurances of data

Tags: python, dictionary, file-io

I know how to do this with Counter() in a basic way (to count the number of times a word appears in a text, for example)... but there are a couple wrenches in my data throwing me off here:
First, I am writing a function that takes in a data file and reads it into python. The data is of local animals and how many were spotted recently. One data file (there are over 400 data files of this form) contains many entries, and some entries may have more than one word to their name (for example, "Whitetail Deer"     18). Each animal and corresponding number is on a new line, and I am trying to read in the data into a dictionary where each animal name is a key and each number is how many were seen (Ill be compiling the data from different locations). 
It is also worth noting that not everything in a data set is actual data; for example, some of the data says LOCATION: SPRING FALLS as a line, which I don't care about. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: provide some code

Comment: i dont have code... i really just need input on how one would do this. I guess if code is needed i have   def function: and that would be it